# Serial Number / Thumb Print of Digital Signature/Certificate

Tags: certificates, windows, digital-signature

When I looked the digital **signature** properties of LSASS.EXE, I am presented with this:

[image]

Which states **Serial Number** `33 00 00 ... 00 CC`. Fair enough.

When I looked the attached digital **certificate** properties, what I see is:
[image: same].

Which has the exact serial number presented in SIGNATURE. Why is this? Is the serial number part of certificate or signature?

Further, the *thumb-print* of **certificate** is mentioned as:

[image: Diff].

Which is a different one.

So, what does uniquely identify a signature - a thumbprint or a serial number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them. A digital signature does not have a recognizable identifier.

You are seeing in the two forms the serial number of the certificate. The serial number is a unique identifier assigned by the Certificate Authority to the certificate and the thumbprint is a hash of the certificate data.

A signature contains a message digest of the signed data (you can see it in form), signed with the private key of the sender. A digital signature has no a identifier but you can know:

- the **identity of the signatory**, because the public key contained in the referenced certificate match with the private key
- That **the message has not been altered**, because it will break the signature